# Private plugin distribution in Craft CMS 3

Tags: craft3

what is the best way to install private plugin in Craft CMS 3? The private plugin is installed in private GitHub repo, but we don't have a custom packagist that we would use, therefore I wonder if there is any option to enable private plugins via composer/plugin-installer?

Comment: You can use private repositories with Composer. The documentation provides an example: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories

Comment: will it work with plugin-installer? What is the difference between installing via composer and plugin-installer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't done this with Craft, but with another Laravel project I was able to add a package from a private repo as follows:

1) In composer.json, after the `require` array, add a new `repositories` array:

```
"require": [
  ...
],
"repositories": [
  {
   "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/YOURGITHUBNAME/your-repo.git"
  }
]
```

2) In the "require" array, add your package:

```
"require": [
  "YOURGITHUBNAME/your-repo": "*",
  ...
]
```

3) Here's the under-documented trick you need to do to get it all working: you must create a "release" in github, and the release name must be the letter "v" followed by the version number (e.g. `v1.0.0`). So go to your repo, click the "Releases" link, then click the "Draft a new release" button. It asks for a tag version and a Release title... I can't remember which of these is the critical one, so just put `v1.0.0` into both of these fields.

4) Now if you run `composer install` it should (hopefully) bring in your private repo package. Might need to provide some kind of authorization / API key to access it if it's a private repo (I'm not sure how exactly this works, but should be fairly easy to find documentation on).

Comment: Technically, your third point is incorrect. In Git, a tag is just an annotated pointer to a commit; in other words, it's a convenient name that you can use to refer to a specific commit hash. As such, you can refer to the hash directly: `"require": {"vendor/package": "dev-master#ed7fa4b0"}`. That said, it's preferable to use version numbers, where possible. More details here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links

Comment: "Preferable" to use version numbers is an understatement! From the docs: *Note: This feature has severe technical limitations, as the composer.json metadata will still be read from the branch name you specify before the hash. You should therefore only use this as a temporary solution during development to remediate transient issues, until you can switch to tagged releases. The Composer team does not actively support this feature and will not accept bug reports related to it.*

Comment: Like I said, your third point is _technically_ incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, the desire for a private plugin is for a one-off client project, where the client owns the custom plugin. If that's the case here, I'd consider just changing the plugin over to be a module, and making it part of the project itself (checked into git, and all that).

e.g.: [Enhancing a Craft CMS 3 Website with a Custom Module](https://nystudio107.com/blog/enhancing-a-craft-cms-3-website-with-a-custom-module)

It's actually pretty easy to convert a plugin over to being a module. FWIW!

Comment: You just nailed my use case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [git](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/20131/57) repository type, "private" plugins can also use Composer's path repository feature to achieve this:

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/plugin-guide.html#loading-your-plugin-into-a-craft-project

https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path

Comment: well, actually I want to use composer. I am not sure, how to incorporate the plugin into current codebase. Adding a repo into a composer.json should be enough, right?

Comment: @bradbell did this ever actually happen?

Comment: Updated my answer... had misunderstood the original question, I suppose.